# How to parse JSON-LD data in java and turn it into a java object

Tags: json-ld

I don't know what kind of format is inside the JSON-LD, but it needs to be converted into a well-defined object.
My question is I don't know what kind of JSON-LD data is uploaded by the client and I don't know if it is possible to convert such data into some object with a well-defined format.
Do you have a solution yet?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't know the structure of the object beforehand, you will probably have to use some generic structure to hold the data in Java. If you use a library like [jsonld-java](https://github.com/jsonld-java/jsonld-java), it will do exactly that. You will work with Maps and Lists and it should be able to accommodate basically any JSON-LD data.

If you did know the target structure (for example, if it were one of several types for which you have a Java class), you could use a library like [JB4JSON-LD](https://github.com/kbss-cvut/jb4jsonld) to load it into an object of that class.

**Disclaimer**: I am the author of the JB4JSON-LD library.